# Unable to pass context from main activity to non-activity using main function

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-assets

I have a `MainActivity class` where I have implemented a main function. This main function calls a non-activity class by passing a context (unable to implement). In the non activity class, I want to access a file from the assets folder (which requires a context, hence the passing of one) and print it in the LogCat. This is how I am trying to do it

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DiseaseAlgo(this).Parser();//Error. Unable to pass context
        return;
    }

    //etc
}
```

NonActivity Class:

```
package com.iotaconcepts.aurum;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DiseaseAlgo
{
    static Context mContext;
    public DiseaseAlgo(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public static void Parser() throws IOException
    {
        AssetManager as=mContext.getAssets();
        String parse=as.open("symp.txt").toString();
        String[] xx=parse.split("\t");
        for(String i:xx)
            Log.w("DiseaseAlgo", i);
    }
}
```

I'm unable to figure out how to pass the context and call the 'DiseaseAlgo' method from this function. I keep getting:

> **package name**.MainActivity.this cannot be referenced from static content

I need this to check the correctness of my text parsing and this is the only way to show it on the LogCat.

Comment: This is really not the way to go, if you have problem debugging  - solve it, don't add another problem.

Comment: If this is not the way to go, please suggest another method and do not downvote the question if you do not have a solution. Thanks

Comment: Actually, I didn't downvote. And I didn't try to solve your question, because if you try and develope for Android, you should make a minimum effort of understanding what you're doing.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the word `this` from a static function. Since the function is static, the class may or may not have an instance. What is calling that function?

If your instance of your activity is calling your `Main()` then pass it's context (`this`) as an arguement so the static function has access to it.

I would guess `Main()` is not from android's functions right? Normaly in a `main()` function you should initialize objects before passing them around so `this` does not make sense, but I don't think android works that way.

Comment: well you have to answer my question, what is calling `Main()` ?

Comment: I'm so sorry for the type. It's 'main'

Comment: @bholagabbar as far as I know `main()` is not the same in C++/Java as in Android Java, why are you using `main()` ? This is an android project right?

Comment: Yes it is. I just wanted main to call the non-activity class, print the data on the logcat and end

Comment: @bholagabbar I'm not sure why you'd call `main()`, try putting the code on an `onCreate()` method, in there your activity has an instance, so you can pass it a `this` arguement.